# Is it possible to run selenium test without starting the Java App on localhost

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, system-testing

I am writing some system test cases with selenium, an was wondering if there is a work around for running these tests without running the java app.

My process to run them is:

1. I build my maven project
2. I write a test
3. Run the java application to start the localhost at 8080 port
4. Run my test cases

I was wondering if there is a way not to do 3 as I am planing on deploying those test cases, and run them in jenkins.

**P.S.** If this question has been asked before, please point out where in comment.

Thank you

Comment: Selenium works as unit test in your project, there is no way to test your app without work inside it. You can run it in background if you want, but you still need to start your app. It takes around 2 min to make a simple checkout, run app, test app, build. Depending on how long your tests takes

Comment: Ok, but _integraton tests_ have a way to configure maven to run them separate fron _unit tests_, is there any way to do the same for _system tests_? @FrancoPapalardo when I ask google I am only finding that there are configured as unit tests.